# How do I select all rows (*) plus some extra rows of my choosing

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT *, `online_since`-NOW() as 'uptime' FROM map_eline_dots
```

I want it to select all columns in `map_eline_dots` plus an extra field "uptime" that contains the result of

```
online_since - NOW()
```

However I'm getting the same result now as I did from

```
SELECT * FROM map_eline_dots
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I HAVE to select every single one of the other 30 columns manually?

Comment: Maybe you have to use brakets and kick all those " ' stuff: SELECT *, (online_since - NOW()) as uptime FROM map_eline_dots

Comment: So online_since is a column in map_eline_dots? If so, is it a datetime column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT map_eline_dots.*, online_since - NOW() as uptime FROM map_eline_dots
```

Or like this.

```
SELECT m.*, online_since - NOW() as uptime FROM map_eline_dots AS m
```

You have to qualify the asterisk, if you select more than just the asterisk. (I removed backticks and quotes to increase readability)

Comment: What's up with all the backticks and quotes? Does that even work? I'd use `SELECT m.*, online_since - NOW() as uptime FROM map_eline_dots AS m`

Comment: I copied from the OP. Backticks are used in MySQL to escape database/table/column literals. But it works with quotes, too. I'll remove them from my answer to be more clear

Comment: I was just wondering about the `as 'uptime'` part. I know about the backticks (even though the uglyness of them makes my head hurt), but I was wondering whether the single quoted alias name would work *(and I don't have MySQL at hand to test it now)*.

Comment: @Johan, standard SQL is double quotes `"`. MySQL is the only RDBMS I know that also supports backticks. Many RDBMS support `'`, and SQL Server / Sybase also allow `[field]`. I guess, you get to choose your poison :-)